# Immutable non-final classes

Tags: java, class, immutability

Is a class still considered as immutable if it can be subclassed(but other rules are kept)? 
For example:

```
abstract class Figure {
abstract double area();
}

class Rectangle extends Figure {
private final double length;
private final double width;

Rectangle(double length, double width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
} 

double area() { return length * width; }
}
```

Is it immutable?

Comment: What is in `Figure`?

Comment: abstract class Figure {
abstract double area();
}

Comment: You should add it as an edit of your question.

Comment: I don't think so, since a subclass could override area (not `final`) or shadow the `private` fields.

Answer (score 2):

The fields `length` and `width` are still immutable for all subclasses (if they are not shadowed by the subclasses fields with the same name).

**But** a subclass can define it's own mutable fields.

So the answer is: it depends.

If you do not inherit other classes of `Rectangle` with mutable fields, than the answer is yes. 
Otherwise no.

Comment: Worse. The subclass can shadow those immutable fields!

Comment: Not to mention that in Java, with `Unsafe` there is no *real* immutable :D

Comment: "Immutable" means that NO object of this class can be changed.  That includes objects of subclasses.  So if it's possible to create subclasses with mutable fields (that is, if the base class is NOT final) and instantiate them, then the base class is NOT immutable.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, if you define it with invariants. But even when it is declared as final, is possible to modify these values and so as a datastructure, it is not immutable at all (e.g. final class with final list) Thats the reason I broke the question down to immutable datastructure instead of only immutable class.

Comment: final is only compiler enforced constraint. You can use reflection, native or jvm bytecode to change final variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Immutable non-final classes

do not exist.

If your class is not `final`, it can be subclassed.

By definition, an immutable class only has invariants. But if it is not `final`, you can subclass it and introduce instance fields which are NOT invariants. So:

```
public class A 
{
    private final int a;

    public A(final int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

is NOT immutable, since you can:

```
public class B
    extends A
{
    // NOT AN INVARIANT
    private int b;

    public B(final int a)
    {
        super(a);
    }

    public void setNonInvariant(final int b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

HOWEVER: class `A` is *thread safe*. But it is not immutable. And class `B` is not thread safe...

Answer (score 0):

If the base class itself is immutable in your example then yes, this is immutable.  In a language such as Java that doesn't support compiler enforced immutability it falls on to you as the developer to handle it- and what means basically is that any object that cannot have its state changed is considered immutable.

In your example above you don't even need to make your variables final - the fact that nothing can change them means it's immutable.